# How to make a web app installable, is it a PWA?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

This demo has an "Install" feature in the menu options bar.
Does anyone know how this can be set up?

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/text-editor/

At the bottom is a link to github src

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a web manifest file and if you want local file caching, a service worker.

Here's a MDN tutorial on making a PWA installable:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Installable_PWAs